# Applying an affine transformation from the matrix to vector representations of spectahedra

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, positive-semidefinite, linear-matrix-inequality, spectrahedra

On page 9, Parrilo wrote$^\color{magenta}{\star}$ that the vector representation of a spectrahedron

$$ S = \left\{ (x_1, \dots, x_m) \in {\Bbb R}^m : A_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m A_i x_i \succeq 0 \right\} $$

is affine equivalent to the set representation of a spectahedron

$$ \left\{ A_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m A_i x_i \mid x \in \mathbb{R}^m \right\} \bigcap \mathcal{S}_+^n $$

Affine equivalent, as far as I understand, means we can produce a bijective linear transformation from set $A$ to set $B$. What function maps from the set of matrices of a spectrahedron to the associated set of vectors?

---

$\color{magenta}{\star}$ [Semidefinite Optimization and Convex Algebraic Geometry](https://www.mit.edu/%7Eparrilo/sdocag/index.html), SIAM, December 2012.

Comment: Are you acquainted with [half-vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Half-vectorization)?